# How to cause onLowMemory on device for tests

Tags: android, low-memory

I want to test our app for low memory cases.

Do you have any ideas, how to cause onLowMemory on devices?

Thank you.

Comment: In the case you want to test your onLowMemory() method, maybe you should just call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just know only one way to do, which is to create a method running in a different thread that does memory leak, make it loop continuously until `onLowMemory()` is called, then stop the thread.

It's nice if anyone shares experiences on this case!

Comment: Indeed, a workmate of me wrote a small app doing something like this. But it works fine in emulator on his mac and doesn't word everytime on my windows pc and my devices

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this doesn't work because onLowMemory() is called when the whole system memory becomes low. each process has a limit, and when that limit is run out, an exception is thrown without affecting the whole system