# onLowMemory event testing

Tags: java, android, testing, memory

I need a test to be able to see if I can somehow use up the system's entire memory so that the system invokes the `onLowMemory()`-event.

I need this to be able to test the behaviour of an application when the memory is running low.
Any tips?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656594/simulate-low-battery-low-memory-in-android), and there's no stopping you from spawning a few hundred processes using adb.

Comment: what is the command to do that ? :/

Comment: for i in $(seq 1 200); do (platform-tools/adb shell &);done # DO NOT DO THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING

Comment: i thought u didnt need if u r using the adb shell hehe

Comment: [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) should work, put the platform-tools dir in the $PATH. Or install busybox on the device, it comes with bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Integer> memoryHog = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(true){
   memoryHog.add(new Integer(5));
}
```

Would something as simple as that work?  Basically loop and add objects until any memory allocated to your program gets used.  Or are you looking for a way to literally use *all* the systems memory?

Comment: exactly, I want a way to use all the system memory. Every process has allocated 16mb/24mb limit. I need a way to know when the system has low memory.

Comment: You should do this in the activity which currently has focus (not belonging to your app) inside an asynctask. That way, Android will try to kill other processes first and those processes are more likely to receive the onLowMemory event.

Comment: Check the comment of michelle in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7674650/1708390). `onLowMemory()` is called when the whole system memory becomes low, not just your app